# Recreate/Reset Root MySQL User/Password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, windows-server-2008, root, mysql-5.1

One of our recently terminated staff members has recently got on a destruction spree, and as we forgot that he had root access to all of our MySQL Databases, he has now wiped them out. None of the instructions from the MySQL guides or various articles on the net are working for resetting the password, so I am thinking he probably deleted the root account.

I have tried about 15 variations of mysql-init.txt, with mysqld, --skip-grant-tables &, and all kinds of other crap that is not working.

Can anyone clue me in on how I can just wipe the current root account (if it is still there) and recreate it with a new password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your databases are gone, why not just uninstall MySQL and do a fresh install.

If your running those commands I assume you have the permissions to do so.

Also, you have to stop MySQL before funning the command
`mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

Comment: We are not entirely sure that the Databases were wiped out. We are having trouble getting ahold of the staff member that handled all of the backups, so we can't get ahold of them for the time being. So we are trying to regain root access to see if the databases still exist.

Comment: I stopped all MySQL services/process instances, that wasn't an issue. I was using mysqld.exe though, as we don't have any msqld_safe in our MySQL installation. Is that something that is still distributed?

Comment: mmm, windows, missed that. Use the `--skip-grant-tables &`  then `mysql -u root` after run your reset query `UPDATE mysql.user SET password=PASSWORD("password") WHERE User='root';` then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` Replace "password" in the parenthesis. Keep in mind I have no idea what works and doesn't with a windows install.

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty much exactly what I have been trying. I get "UPDATE command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'user'